Robot Framework Date Validation
I have a situation where i need to test a Rest API response in Robot Framework and validate that whether the Date (For example incidentDate field in below response) is available in response or its coming as empty. I am not sure how should i verify the date part and if date is available the test should pass else it should fail.
Language Used: Python & Version is 3.10.12.
Library Used: Selenium library is being used in Robot Framework.
Example of API response:
"claimIncident": [
        {
            "Deduction": "deductible",
            "incidentDate": "2024-05-02",
            "commitmentOfPayment": true,
            "Compensation": "1/1"
        }
]


Usually when testing Rest API, we use RequestsLibrary (maybe also combined with SeleniumLibrary or Browser) to obtain the request response.
Anyway, when you have a know response, like you show, as a JSON or a dictionary, you can inspect the key incidentDate and its value.
The API may not send the key when empty, or may set some known value to represent empty.
Try to detail the steps you need (pseudo-code), so we can give a better answer.

I will show you the steps and the Robot Framework code for this assertion:

Convert the response to json using .json() built-in function.
Get the value of "incidentDate" field in the response json.
Do the assertion whether it is empty.

Here is the code that I tried and it worked:
${incident_date}=    Get Value From Json     ${response.json()}     $.claimIncident[0].incidentDate
Should Not Be Equal    ${date[0]}    ${EMPTY}


${response} is the variable that holds your request's response. For example ${response}=    GET On Session      session_name    uri.
Please don't forget to import JSONLibrary.

